# __DIR__ VS using Reflection

Tags: php, symfony

In Symfony2, I saw the code like below:

```
    if (null === $this->rootDir) {
        $r = new \ReflectionObject($this);
        $this->rootDir = dirname($r->getFileName());
    }
```

why not just use the `__DIR__`?

```
    if (null === $this->rootDir) {
        $this->rootDir = __DIR__;
    }
```

What is difference between them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`__DIR__` returns the directory of the file where it is called. The Symphony2 code returns the directory of where the class is defined, which most likely is a different file.

Comment: But if the code is not part of the class definition how can they use "$this"?

Comment: Ah, yeah... If this code is in parent class, which is extended, `__DIR__` will be directory of *parent* class, while `dirname($r->getFileName())` will be directory of *child* class.

Answer (score 2):

As PHP manual states:

- **DIR** returns the directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned
- **FILE** returns the full path and filename of the file. If used inside an include, the name of the included file is returned.

So these constants always returns paths of the file where there are used. However, I suppose that it is not the expected behaviour in the code snippet you cited. Possibly the code resides in some base class, while it can be invoked from extending classes. If we want to get the path to the current class, the first way is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

`__DIR__` exists only in PHP 5.3. Before 5.3, we had to use `dirname(__FILE__)` or something similar.

Comment: @xdazz, you might check earlier versions of Symfony2 - do they have such code? If yes, my bet is that it was just copy-pasted to Symfony2.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because `__DIR__` will return the directory of the script that was initially invoked. In the code example, you would get the directory of the object's class. I may be wrong though have not tried this yet please correct me anyone if I am.

Comment: Are there any examples that __DIR__ is different with the directory of the object's class?

Comment: __DIR__ always gives you the CURRENT directory not the initial one

Comment: According to Sander, DIR returns directory of the script where it is called. I'll still run a quick test tomorrow to put my mind at ease.

Comment: You have nice free +1 from me by mistake, considering your comment is wrong.